# Not getting the profile image from html form but other datas are getting

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-views, django-templates

this is the profile model

```
   class Profile(models.Model):
      user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      id_user=models.IntegerField()
      bio=models.TextField(blank=True)
      profileimg=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images',default='defaultdp.png')
      location=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
    
       return self.user.username
```

this is the html form

```
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {%csrf_token%}
       <div class="col-span-2">
                <label for=""> Profile Picture</label>
                <img height="100" width="100" src="{{user_profile.profileimg.url}}">                
                <input type="file" name="profileimg" placeholder="" class="shadow-none bg-gray-100">
        </div>
    <form>
```

this is views.py

```
    @login_required(login_url='signin') 
    def settings(request):
      user_profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
      if request.method == 'POST':

         if request.FILES.get('image')==None:
            image=user_profile.profileimg
            bio=request.POST ['bio']
            location=request.POST['location']

            user_profile.profileimg=image
            user_profile.bio=bio
            user_profile.location=location
            user_profile.save()
    
        if request.FILES.get('image')!=None:
            image=request.FILES.get('image')
            bio=request.POST ['bio']
            location=request.POST['location']

            user_profile.profileimg=image
            user_profile.bio=bio
            user_profile.location=location
            user_profile.save()
       return redirect('settings')
    
    return render(request,'setting.html',{'user_profile': user_profile})
```

the profile image which I am getting is the defaultdp.png which is the default pic if no file is getting uploaded. I think the file i am uploading is not getting saved on the database or I dont know what is happening here. could anyone please help me to sort it out..?
If I am missing any kind of code snippet here for debugging kindly mention it.I will edit the question with the mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check the static and media configuration in settings.py file from project folder.

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images/') # 'images' is my media folder in project folder.
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and add the following in urls.py of project folder.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and now add media context processor in settings.py file

```
    TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            #here add your context Processors
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Check about static media files handling in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Sry for wasting your time the problem was with a typo.See the name="profileimg" in html for the profile image.But I was searching for "image" in views.py thats why its not getting the image.LOL I lost my entire day debugging this.